# Angular & Symfony: Why should we use token system for authentication?

Tags: angular, symfony, jwt, access-token, restful-authentication

I'm working on a project that uses Angular as frontend and Symfony as backend, and for now I'm using Token system for authentication and as we know the steps are:

- Provide username and password to the backend
- Generate token
- Save it client side using `localStorage`
- Check if token has been expired and refresh it again each time you send a request to the backend

And in order to achieve this I had to install three bundles:
 - [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle): For creating a token system
 - [JWTRefreshTokenBundle](https://github.com/gesdinet/JWTRefreshTokenBundle): For refreshing token system
 - [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle): To work with CORS requests

So my question is why should we use these whole things when we can use Symfony's default authentication system?!
**Please correct me if I'm wrong**:
We can simply use these steps and not install any additional bundle:

- Provide username and password to the backend
- Authenticate user using symfony's default authentication system (of
  course after configuring the firewall)
- And each time we send a request (in the controller) we can check if
  user is logged in using this methode `$this->getUser();` (which will
  return null if he is not connected)

And for the CORS requests we can simply create a custom Response with header `array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=> '*')` let's say something like this:

```
class APIResponse extends Response
{
    function __construct($content, $status = 201, array $headers = array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'))
    {
        if(is_array($content)) parent::__construct(json_encode($content), $status, $headers);
        else throw new LogicException('The response must be an array, '.gettype($content).' given');
    }
}
```

It was just a thought and I hope you guys point me to the right direction and explain why should we use token over symfony's default authentication system.

Comment: A token allows you to skip storing session data on the server.  A stateless solution.  But as long as that is not a problem then the Symfony security system is fine.  Do look at using the isGranted functionality instead of getUser.  And be aware that while there is a natural tendency to look for bundles to implement this sort of stuff, bundles can often be overkill.  A bit of code specific to your needs is often all you really need.

Comment: @Cerad exactly I don't like to install a lot of bundles for a small application, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not tell **you have to use** particular solutions. You can choose whatever you want.

JWT is recently really trendy. It is nice to know how JWT is working. But you do not have to use JWT style authorization.

JWT is really powerful for big systems with a thousands of registered users because **it can reduce database usage** (reduce number of queries). It is because token handling is moved from serwer side to client side.

For smaller systems I prefer to use api-keys, session tokens etc. Like you wrote it is too much work with JWT there.

Comment: yeah too much work using JWT, so you mean I can use my idea (default authentication) instead of JWT ?